Contiguous sequence in arrays inside dataframe - polars
Since asking this, I started looking into using polars to handle my data also. From the docs for map_rows and in general, there are many warnings about using python functions rather than their own expression system as it's much slower. Is it possible to use polars expressions to find contiguous sequences in dataframe rows?
An extra question would be if the @njit decorator on my existing UDF (from the previous question) has any effect on the running of the polars map_rows. If it's relevant I'm currently using the polars Array type instead of List (but I can change if needed).
EDIT:
My dataframe (csv format) has a shape like:
Myname,"1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5",AnotherName

The length of the array in the middle is fixed, but I don't necessarily know how long the strides will be (4 long in this case).
As stated before I'm currently using my previous question and a UDF which I'm applying to many rows with the intention of filtering them.

Maybe you can just ask the actual question in terms of Polars? With an example input/output dataframe. Are you looking to find Run-lengths > 1? i.e. pl.Series([1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,6,7]).rle()

@jqurious I was hoping to "translate" the other question I asked. I'm looking for a way to do arbitrary length runs without using UDFs (this is definitely possible but much slower)

If the question is to find 4,4,4,4 in this example, Polars has .rle() built in. You can then filter lengths > 1. map_rows is effectively "pointless" - I am not really sure why it exists in Polars.

As @jqurious mentioned, it'd be much easier to help if you provided an actual example of polars code showing the input dataframe along with the expected result. The problem sounds like it can be handled using native polars.

So you are actually starting with CSV data? Can you show an actual minimal example with at least 2 inputs, along with the expected output? Do you want to find length N exactly? Or >= N? It's not entirely clear.

It sounds like you have:
df = pl.read_csv(b"""
name,array,other
a,"1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5",e
b,"1,2,3,4,6,6,6",f
c,"1,2,2,2,2,3,4,6,6,6",g
d,"1,1,1,1,1",h
""").with_columns(
   array = pl.format("[{}]", "array").str.json_decode()
).with_row_index()

shape: (4, 4)
┌───────┬──────┬────────────────────────────────┬───────┐
│ index ┆ name ┆ array                          ┆ other │
│ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---                            ┆ ---   │
│ u32   ┆ str  ┆ list[i64]                      ┆ str   │
╞═══════╪══════╪════════════════════════════════╪═══════╡
│ 0     ┆ a    ┆ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]       ┆ e     │
│ 1     ┆ b    ┆ [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6]          ┆ f     │
│ 2     ┆ c    ┆ [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6] ┆ g     │
│ 3     ┆ d    ┆ [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]                ┆ h     │
└───────┴──────┴────────────────────────────────┴───────┘

And you want to test if any Run-length encoding >= N exists in the array column.
Polars comes with rle and rle_id expressions: .rle()
.flatten() + .over("index") is one way to "emulate" a row-based list operation.
df.with_columns(
   pl.col("array").flatten().rle().struct["lengths"].max().over("index")
     .alias("rle_max_len")
)

shape: (4, 5)
┌───────┬──────┬────────────────────────────────┬───────┬─────────────┐
│ index ┆ name ┆ array                          ┆ other ┆ rle_max_len │
│ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---                            ┆ ---   ┆ ---         │
│ u32   ┆ str  ┆ list[i64]                      ┆ str   ┆ i32         │
╞═══════╪══════╪════════════════════════════════╪═══════╪═════════════╡
│ 0     ┆ a    ┆ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]       ┆ e     ┆ 4           │
│ 1     ┆ b    ┆ [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6]          ┆ f     ┆ 3           │
│ 2     ┆ c    ┆ [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6] ┆ g     ┆ 4           │
│ 3     ┆ d    ┆ [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]                ┆ h     ┆ 5           │
└───────┴──────┴────────────────────────────────┴───────┴─────────────┘

It's essentially the same as doing:
(df.group_by("index")
   .agg(
      pl.all().first(),
      rle_max_len = pl.col("array").flatten().rle().struct["lengths"].max()
   )
)

If you don't need the length, it can be passed directly to .filter() if desired.
df.filter(
   pl.col("array").flatten().rle().struct["lengths"].max().over("index") > 3
)

shape: (3, 4)
┌───────┬──────┬────────────────────────────────┬───────┐
│ index ┆ name ┆ array                          ┆ other │
│ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---                            ┆ ---   │
│ u32   ┆ str  ┆ list[i64]                      ┆ str   │
╞═══════╪══════╪════════════════════════════════╪═══════╡
│ 0     ┆ a    ┆ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]       ┆ e     │
│ 2     ┆ c    ┆ [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6] ┆ g     │
│ 3     ┆ d    ┆ [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]                ┆ h     │
└───────┴──────┴────────────────────────────────┴───────┘

